# WebView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync does not fill the fields on the page

Tags: c#, webview2

I have a code like below,

```
public partial class LawView : UserControl
{
    public LawView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeAsync();
    }

    async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        webView.Source = new System.Uri("https://blahblah.com.pl/");
        webView.Focus();
        await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementById('user').value = 'blahblahusername'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'blahpassword'; })()");
        await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementsByName('wp-submit')[0].click(); })()");
    }
}
```

in the console, the scripts run without any problems, but when I run them in the application, the fields in the open page do not fill me up. What am I doing wrong? Is there something missing?

I've already searched stackoverflow and other sites. I found nothing to lead me to a solution. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5):

After setting the `Source` property you need to wait for the page to actually load. You can use the [NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1245.22) event or the [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.domcontentloaded?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1245.22) for this. Note that `NavigationCompleted` is called for successful and unsuccessful navigations.

1. The example below uses a simple `extension` method to wrap the `NavigationCompleted` event. The method uses the `Navigate` method instead of setting the `Source` property.

```cs
// Create a static class and add the following extension method
// Add using System.Threading.Tasks;
public static Task NavigateToAsync(this CoreWebView2 coreWebView2, string url)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

    EventHandler<CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs> evt = null;

    evt = async (s, args) =>
    {
        coreWebView2.NavigationCompleted -= evt;

        if (args.IsSuccess)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception("Nav Failed With Error:" + args.WebErrorStatus.ToString()));
        }
    };

    coreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += evt;

    coreWebView2.Navigate(url);

    return tcs.Task;
}

// Use extension method in your code.
async void InitializeAsync()
{
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    
    try
    {
        await webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToAsync("https://klimedsoft.pl/strefa-klienta/");
        webView.Focus();

        // now execute your javascript
        await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementById('user').value = 'blahblahusername'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'blahpassword'; })()");
        await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementsByName('wp-submit')[0].click(); })()");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: Handle error
    }
}
```

2. Alternatively you can use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.domcontentloaded?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1245.22) event directly, it's only called upon successful navigation.

```cs
async void InitializeAsync()
{
  await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
  webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded;
  webView.Source = new System.Uri("https://klimedsoft.pl/strefa-klienta/");

}

private async void OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded(object sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs arg)
{
  webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded -= OnWebViewDOMContentLoaded;

  webView.Focus();
  
 // now execute your javascript
 await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementById('user').value = 'blahblahusername'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'blahpassword'; })()");
 await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementsByName('wp-submit')[0].click(); })()");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate if the web view navigated to the page at all.

Try using the `Navigate(string url)` on the Core viewer.
The main issue is generally that we need to wait for the page load to complete before it will be ready to execute scripts. When you run this in the web console, you are doing so only after the page has loaded.

[This response from @amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72681711/1690217) is generally the accepted solution for converting an event based API (EAP) to a Task based API (TAP). This pattern is generally referred to as a *TAP Wrapper* or *TAP Extension*. Find more information on that here:

- [From APM to TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-apm-to-tap)

My previous solution (which I will leave below) was a quick and dirty wait loop, we should however use `SemiphoreSlim` instead of thread blocking logic to achieve the same thing. You can find out more information here:

- [Waiting for an event to fire while using SemaphoreSlim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61334469/1690217)

This is a solution using `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _waitForWebViewToLoad;
async void InitializeAsync()
{
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    _waitForWebViewToLoad = new SemaphoreSlim(0,1);
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
    webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://klimedsoft.pl/strefa-klienta/");
    webView.Focus();
    await _waitForWebViewToLoad.WaitAsync();

    // now execute your javascripts
    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementById('user').value = 'blahblahusername'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'blahpassword'; })()");
    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementsByName('wp-submit')[0].click(); })()");
}

private void CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted -= CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
    _waitForWebViewToLoad.Release();
}
```

The following is a similar approach that uses a simple boolean flag to indicate when the event has fired, the difference here it uses an infinite loop that blocks and then waits for 100 milliseconds. If you find yourself using this style of code, then `SemaphoreSlim` was designed specifically to solve this problem without blocking the current thread:

```
async void InitializeAsync()
{
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
    navComplete = false;
    webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://klimedsoft.pl/strefa-klienta/");
    webView.Focus();
    while(!navComplete)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    
    // now execute your javascripts
    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementById('user').value = 'blahblahusername'; document.getElementById('password').value = 'blahpassword'; })()");
    await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { document.getElementsByName('wp-submit')[0].click(); })()");
}

bool navComplete = false;
private void CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted -= CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
    navComplete = true;
}
```

Comment: Waiting in a loop is not the correct way to use the `NavigationCompleted` event (or other events for that matter).

Comment: While I agree, when you are automating UX like this its hard to avoid. It would be better if we didn't have to use events at all for this, but that is not an option. Call it commercial pragmatism if it makes you feel better. Look at the amount of effort it takes to in the response from [@amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72681711/1690217), while that is an elegant solution, its a lot of code for @Pepe to digest that will only spawn new questions. If you go with the 2nd option then the logic becomes segmented and tightly coupled. You get to choose your poison really ;)

Comment: Now if you could avoid using events, then it would be ok, but you still use events and even with more code lines than the 2nd approach.

Comment: A better idea than busy waiting would be to use a `SemaphoreSlim(0, 1)`, await it and release in the event.

Comment: We're scraping screens here, the lines of code difference is not a bit deal, it's essentially the same with a variable declaration and a wait loop. The problem with the 2nd approach is the logic is now split up across multiple methods, in fact the pattern of action and wait is going to come up a lot with WebView automation because you need to wait for the page to load, often we aren't waiting for the whole page, but for some specific operation or api call to be made, in these cases a first principals wait-for-flag anti pattern is just plain practical. Yes `SemiphoreSlim` would be better.

Comment: @PoulBak just edited to address your concerns and demonstrate how `SemiphoreSlim` improves this style of code

Comment: I like that better, removed the downvote.

Comment: SemaphoreSlim implements IDisposable so generally speaking should be explicitly disposed. NavigationCompleted is called for successful and unsuccessful navigations, neither example deals with the the possible error.